# class definition error: ‘SP’ is not a template type

Tags: c++

I am tyring a custom implementation of smart pointers. The code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
class Person
{
    int age;
    std::string pName;

    public:
        Person(): pName(0),age(0)
        {
        }
        Person(std::string pName, int age): pName(pName), age(age)
        {
        }
        ~Person()
        {
        }

        void Display()
        {
            std::cout << "Name: " << pName << "Age: " << age << std::endl;
        }
        void Shout()
        {
            std::cout << "Ooooooooooooooooooo" << std::endl;

        }
};
```

/*Smart Pointer Interface */

```
class SP
{
private:
    Person* pData; // pointer to person class
public:
    SP(Person* pValue) : pData(pValue)
    {

    }
    ~SP()
    {
        /*pointer no longer requried*/
        delete pData;
    }

    Person& operator* ()
    {
        return *pData;
    }

    Person* operator-> ()
    {
        return pData;
    }
};
```

Trying to make it more generic.

```
template < typename T > class SP
{
    private:
       T* pData; // Generic pointer to be stored
    public:
       SP(T *pValue) : pData(pValue)
       {
       }
       ~SP()
       {
          delete pData;
       }

       T& operator*()
       {
          return *pData;
       }

       T * operator->()
       {
          return pData;
       }
};

int main()
{
    SP<PERSON> p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    p->Display();
    {
        SP<PERSON> q = p;
        q->Display();
        /*Destructor of q will be called here..*/
    }
    p->Display();
    /*Destructor of p will be called here.*/
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the above code I get the error.

```
smart_pointers.cpp:90:31: error: ‘SP’ is not a template type
 template < typename T > class SP
                               ^
smart_pointers.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
smart_pointers.cpp:116:5: error: ‘SP’ is not a template
     SP<PERSON> p(new Person("Scott", 25));
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why the -1 marking. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `SP` obviously is a template, so please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BaummitAugen - What I have provided is a simple complete verifiable example.

Comment: [It does not reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8932e63e01fbcbc) the error, so it is not a MCVE.

Comment: The error says the problem is on line 90, so there are 90 lines of code before `template < typename T > class SP` that you haven't provided.

Comment: @ksfone - I have the habit of comment my code extensively while learning. I am able to get the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two definitions of the same class.

```
struct S {};
template<typename T> struct S{};
```

reproduces your compiler error: http://ideone.com/7KpAPl

In this case, you only need the template definition.